# Group by and selecting last value respecting the order in time

Tags: sql-server, time, group-by

I have the following data in MSSQL:

```
declare @TEMP table (Period int, Color varchar(20), Rate int)
insert into @TEMP values(201601, 'Blue', 10)
insert into @TEMP values(201602, 'Blue', 10)
insert into @TEMP values(201603, 'Blue', 11)
insert into @TEMP values(201604, 'Red',  11)
insert into @TEMP values(201605, 'Red',  12)
insert into @TEMP values(201606, 'Blue', 13)
insert into @TEMP values(201607, 'Blue', 13)
insert into @TEMP values(201608, 'Blue', 14)
insert into @TEMP values(201609, 'Blue', 14)
insert into @TEMP values(201610, 'Blue', 14)
insert into @TEMP values(201611, 'Blue', 14)
insert into @TEMP values(201612, 'Blue', 14)

SELECT * FROM @TEMP
```

I would like to group by the Color, while keeping the "order of time". So the first 3 blue records would be grouped independent of the last 7 blue records.
Eventually, I'd like to select the "latest" row within the group.

The output would be:

```
    Period  |   Color   |   Rate
    ------  |   -----   |   ----
    201603  |   Blue    |   11
    201605  |   Red     |   12
    201612  |   Blue    |   14
    ------  |   -----   |   ----
```

Comment: `So the first 3 blue records would be grouped independent of the last 7 blue records`.There is no first and last in SQL,until you order by ..There must be some logic to determine groups.plus 1 for sample data

Comment: like always first 3 order by date fall in one group,rest in other group

Comment: Thanks for the DDL, but pls don't use (MAX) datatypes unless needed.

Comment: updated the max to 20, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you're using some newer version of SQL Server, because of the window functions.

Here's the solution:

```
;with x as (
    select *, case when lag(color) over(order by period) = color then 0 else 1 end as g
    from @temp
),
y as (
    select *, sum(g) over(order by period) gg
    from x
),
z as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by gg order by period desc) rn
    from y
)
select period, color, rate from z where rn = 1
```

Comment: Hi Dean, yes working on Standard 16, so definitely works.
The output looks exactly how i want it. I'll work through the steps and figure out the logic. Thanks!

Comment: As for the steps - yes, it looks ugly, but the sad fact is that you can't compose window functions, thus the multiple CTEs.